# Wi-fi security using WPA or WEP

Tags: encryption, authentication, wifi, wireless

In current years we have used WPA and WPA 2 for the encryption of data sent over an 802.11 network. But in the past WEP is used . From time to time, many people say that WEP (Wired Equivalent Privacy) is a rather poor way of protecting data sent over an 802.11 wireless network.  Is there any reason behind?  What is the advantage of using WPA for the encryption of data sent over an 802.11 network ?

Comment: In short:  Methods currently exist which allow WEP to be broken within a matter of minutes, if not seconds.  Check out the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy#Flaws).

Comment: I've heard people suggest that NetworkManager should add a plugin to crack WEP, since it's faster than waiting for a user to type the password.

Comment: WEP ceased to be considered security a long time ago and doesn't protect data at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WEP has a flaw that renders it essentially unsecure. If you look at [How does WEP wireless security work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17434/how-wep-wireless-security-works) it explains in better detail.

WPA(2) has fixed that vulnerability but they also suffer from their own problems.

- [WPA significantly less secure than WPA2?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4252/wpa-significantly-less-secure-than-wpa2)
- [WiFi WPA cracking with Reaver](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14913/wifi-wpa-cracking-with-reaver)
- [How to get hold of and use WPA session keys?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4498/how-to-get-hold-of-and-use-wpa-session-keys?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the conclusion of [this article](http://compudent.blogspot.dk/2006/09/wireless-wep-vs-wpa-vs-wpa2.html) the password may be your weakest point.

However, if you have a "secure" password you should be good to go.

But yes, WEP is [full of flaws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy#Flaws).

WPA also [has some problems](http://pcworld.about.net/od/securit1/New-Attack-Cracks-Common-Wi-Fi.htm).

Use WP2 and **make sure to disable WPS!**